# Iterative method to assign values to a new variable based on the values of a preexisting variable in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a new variable "Timeelapsed" that measures the amount of time elapsed since the beginning of the study for each observation - this new variable is based on the preexisting variable "Year".

I created a program that outputs the correct amount of years that have elapsed since the beginning of the study for each observation. However, this code is inefficient and uses repeated if statements. I attempted using nested for/if loops to make the code more efficient, but none of my newer programs work properly. I would appreciate any help in making my code more efficient.

Working code:

```
Timeelasped <- rep(NA, length((data$Year)))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(data$Year[i]==2007) {
    Timeelasped[i] <- 0
  }
  if(data$Year[i]==2008) {
    Timeelasped[i] <- 1
  }
  if(data$Year[i]==2009) {
    Timeelasped[i] <- 2
  }
}
```

Current Output:

> Timeelapsed
>   0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

Comment: Use `dplyr` and `case_when`. Here is the code, `Data %>% mutate(TimeElapsed = case_when(Year == 2007 ~ 0,
                                     Year == 2008 ~ 1,
                                     Year == 2009 ~ 2
                                     ))`

Comment: Is the start year a constant? If so, just set is as start_year <- 2007 and then calculate Timeelapsed as data$Timeelapsed <- data$Year - start_year

Answer (score 0):

If year is just a numeric value (do you get `TRUE` when you write `is.numeric(data1[,'year'])`?) per observation rather than a date/time object then this will work, no need for anything complex!

```
# dummy data
data1 <- data.frame('year' = c(2007, 2008, 2008, 2009))

# solution 
data1[,'elapsed'] <- data1[,'year'] - 2007
```

Output:

```
  year elapsed
1 2007       0
2 2008       1
3 2008       1
4 2009       2
```

If it is a date/time then look into the `difftime` function